# Applescript to insert current date into subject line of email and the body of the email to be conditional depending on day sent

Tags: applescript, automator

I am trying to finish a workflow in Automator and the only step left is to create an email that's contents are dependent on the day in which it's built.

The subject of the Outlook email needs to contain the current date and the body of the email needs an if statement to check if today is a Monday or a Friday to allow for the email to say either "...for the current week" or "...for the upcoming week".

Is this possible? I tried to use the Automator "Create New Outlook Mail Message" but was unable to apply any kinds of conditions inside so I assume raw Applescript is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, raw Applescript is the way to go. I'm surprised you can't find examples for how to 1. get today's date, 2. compare to your target date, 3. create new email in Outlook with a given subject and body content

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AppleScript will be more flexible. in your Automator flow, add an action "run Applescript" and replace the script by :

```
on run {input, parameters}
set My_Destinataire to "myfriend@gmail.com" -- assign here the email address

set Wday to first word of date string of (current date) -- get the days of the week in local language
if Wday is in {"Saturday", "Sunday"} then -- fill subject and content for week end
set My_Subject to "we are " & Wday & " !"
set My_Content to "this email is for next upcoming week…"
else -- fill subject and content with message for working days
set My_Subject to "we are " & Wday & ", an other working day !"
set My_Content to "this email is for current week…"
end if

tell application "Microsoft Outlook" -- creation of the new email itself
activate
set NewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:My_Subject, content:My_Content}
make new recipient at NewMessage with properties {email address:{name:"", address:My_Destinataire}}
send newMessage -- if you want to send the message directly without checking it
end tell
return input
end run
```

You have to adjust to pass in "input" the email address and you must adjust subject/content strings to what you need for working days and week end.

Comment: Sorry Jweaks, I missed the word "Outlook". I just updated the script, replacing "Mail" by "Microsoft Outlook". Syntaxe is almost the same. Main difference is to add recipients.

Comment: I'd use it for mail - what would the differences be? Is the only difference replacing 'Microsoft Outlook' with 'Mail'?

Comment: Yes, replace "Mail" by "Microsoft Outlook", but also, the line adding recipients: in Mail, it is : make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:"", address:Mon_Destinataire}